# Is it necessary to add "being" here?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

> The meeting, held at a time when the world is facing growing uncertainties, is widely expected to bring positive energy to global well-being.

or

> The meeting, **being** held at a time when the world is facing growing uncertainties, is widely expected to bring positive energy to global well-being.

Is the word "being" necessary here and what is the difference?

Comment: This is a tricky one, but in my opinion I think its better to put the "being".  The reason I think this is that "held" is in the past tense which conflicts slightly with the other parts of the sentence (..."is expected") and makes it more clear that the meeting is currently taking place or is in the future.